# Effective Permittivity in Layered Dielectrics around Point-Charge

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, coulombs-law, dielectric

Suppose you have a point charge at the center of a spherical dielectric of radius $\Delta x_1$ and permittivity $\varepsilon_1$. Surrounding this dielectric you have successive layers of dielectrics with thickness $\Delta x_2, \cdots, \Delta x_N$ and permittivities $\varepsilon_2, \cdots, \varepsilon_N$.

What would the effective permittivity $\varepsilon_\text{eff}(r)$ be for the Coulombs potential

$$
V(r) = \frac{q_\text{A}q_\text{B}}{4\pi\varepsilon_\text{eff} r}
$$
experienced between the central point charge and a point charge a distance $r$ away?

See figure below for illustration:

[image: Central point charge surrounded by dielectrics]

Comment: Why don't you take Gauß' law with spherical symmetry and your assumption on the potential with an effective permeability and solve the resulting differential equation?

Comment: @krisheli The solution to Gauß law is $\psi=C_1/r + C_2$ for any of the sections with constant permittivity. Do you agree that you could use that the electric potential $\psi$ and $\epsilon \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial r}$ have to be continuous over any boundary to solve for the constants?

Comment: Sounds reasonable, yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take into account the effect of the outer charge on the polarization of the spheres, then the answer cannot be written in the Coulomb form.

If you ignore the effect of the outer charge or assume that the distance is long so the only important term in the potential is the monopole term, then:
$$V(r)=\frac{q_A q_B}{4\pi \epsilon r}$$

The inner spheres are not important, since the net charge on their outer and inner surfaces are opposite and their net electrix field is zero outside of the spheres.

Comment: Thank you. I believe your comments are correct. However, I am wondering whether it is possible to find an $\epsilon_\text{eff}(r)$ expression for the system as presented (that is, no polarization from $q_B but for possibly short distances).